# Laravel Passport + Ionic User Authentication issue

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-5.4, laravel-passport

I have an application in Laravel running on a live server and I am trying to consume its API with an Ionic application using Passport for the user authentication and the retrieval of the access_token.

After I have successfully retrieved the access_token making a request to the url: https://my-app.com/oauth/token, I save the access_token and I make a simple GET request to get a "hello" message that uses the "auth:api" middleware.

This GET request, when done to the live server returns a 401 status code. On the other hand, when I follow the same steps but on the localhost then it works fine.

All these steps are done on the Ionic application as well as the Postman application. And both ways yield the same results.

I really don't know what could be wrong. I have followed instruction online and on the laravel documentation.

Comment: Is this a CORS issue? Have you allowed an non-local origin?

Comment: I have configure CORS through the barryvdh/laravel-cors package.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** First check that you added the passport middleware into your `app\Http\Kernel.php` > `$routeMiddleware` array.
**2)** Then protect routes with this passport middleware in `app\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php`, like:

```
protected function mapApiRoutes()
{
    Route::prefix('api')
         ->middleware('client_credentials')
         ->namespace($this->namespace)
         ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
}
```

For more detail, you can check this [answer source](https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/101).